# Как в js при клике по баттону скрыть эту кнопку и на этом же месте показать другую

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

История такая: есть кнопка "Хочу!". Когда я нажимаю на нее, вызывается функция, а потом эта кнопка должна скрываться и и на месте этой кнопки должен показывать div, состоящий из +,кол-во,- (кнопка увеличить на 1, количество товара и кнопка уменьшить на 1).

Какие варианты есть? у меня кнопка и div не привязаны друг с другом. Товаров много, на заметку. Я вот думал div-у привязать id товара, как и кнопке. И если id кнопки == id div-а, то кнопка hidden, а div showed. Мне бы на js это реализовать, а то навыков недостаточно, долблюсь уже 4 день((

Comment: Покажите ваш код `js`, разметку `html`, и стили `css`. В виде сниппета, который можно выполнить.Иначе мы никак не сможем вам помочь!

Comment: http://a0197907.xsph.ru/ Вот сайт, здесь можно посмотреть. Там много кнопок "хочу", при клике на нее, товар добавляется в корзину, если кликаешь повторно, то инкремент идет. А я хочу, чтобы вместо инкремента кнопка ХОЧУ скрывалась, а блок div с инкрементом и декрементом открывался

Comment: Ссылки на сайты здесь не приветствуются. Внесите весь соответствующий код в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Ну да, из описания слабо понятно, что ты хочешь. 
Но , если я верно понял, то мыслишь ты верно. У тебя  у кнопки "хочу" и инпута кол-ва должен быть в идеале 1 родитель ( чтобы при скрытии у тебя не уплыло все) и через jquery что то такое:

```
$('.hochu').click(function(e){
  //что делает кнопка "хочу"
  $(this).hide();
  $('.selectCount').show();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй в следующий раз объяснять по-лучше, если я правильно тебя понимаю то тебе достаточно удалить этот блок и когда ты вызовишь метод show у дива, тогда он встанет на место кнопки "хочу".

```
$('#clickMe').on('click', function() {
    $(this).remove();
    $('.more').show();
})
```

Вот пример https://jsfiddle.net/jsq5oLkn/5/

Comment: Добрый день. Да, это то, что мне нужно. Только кнопок таких 75 и нужно, как я понял, пройтись по каждому товару с помощью цикла. через for или forEach лучше?

Comment: @ДенисРыбачек думаю лучше будет через each(это forEach только на [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) )

Comment: А зачем вам цикл? Или  я чего то не понимаю? 
У вас при нажатии на КОНКРЕТНУЮ кнопку должна скрываться ТОЛЬКО ОНА и на ее месте появляться инпут выбора,так?

Comment: @dmitriy_vlz возможно OP хотел отрисовать эти кнопки при помощи цикла, а не вручную

Comment: Изначально нужно все кнопки собрать, чтобы делать с ними что либо же

Comment: Ну если только что бы не отрисовывать , тогда понятно.

Comment: В общем, для кнопки не надо цикл использовать, там по this идет обращение, а вот если див без цикла делать, то при нажатии любой кнопки id = 1 у div выскакивает. как пройтись по диву в Js? я не могу их собрать queryselectorall почему-то, выскакивает nodelist[].

Comment: @ДенисРыбачек $('div').forEach(item => {}) . Если мой ответ с кнопками помог, отметь пожалуйста его как правильный

Comment: @РомаБойко хорошо, item => {} это синтаксис js? типа как for(item in array) ?

Comment: @ДенисРыбачек Да, это синтаксис js es6, а именно [стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). В es5 будет выглядеть примерно так $('div').forEach(function(item) {})